# jquery add element then select (for overwriting) added text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple bit of code for adding new bullet points to a list. New bullet points have the generic text of 'Your new bullet' which the user then edits. Is there any way that once the new bullet point is added the generic text is selected ready for overwriting.

My code looks like this....

```js
$(document).on("click", "#addNewBullet", function(){
    $('<li class="bullet editable" contentEditable="true">Your new bullet</li>').insertBefore('#addNewBullet')
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bulletPoints" id="bullets">
<li class="bullet" contenteditable="true">Bullet1</li>
<li class="bullet" contenteditable="true">Bullet2</li>
<li class="bullet" contenteditable="true">Bullet3</li>
<div id="addNewBullet">+ Add</div>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure, here you go -> **http://jsfiddle.net/d7m2o9dn/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.focus()` and then **select all** the text:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#addNewBullet", function() {
  $('<li class="bullet editable" contentEditable="true">Your new bullet</li>').insertBefore('#addNewBullet').focus();
  document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bulletPoints" id="bullets">
  <li class="bullet" contenteditable="true">Bullet1</li>
  <li class="bullet" contenteditable="true">Bullet2</li>
  <li class="bullet" contenteditable="true">Bullet3</li>
  <div id="addNewBullet">+ Add</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `focus` and i have added functon `selectText` to select the all the text, so easy to edit the text.

```js
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
   var doc = document;
   var element = this[0];
   console.log(this, element);
   if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
       var range = document.body.createTextRange();
       range.moveToElementText(element);
       range.select();
   } else if (window.getSelection) {
       var selection = window.getSelection();        
       var range = document.createRange();
       range.selectNodeContents(element);
       selection.removeAllRanges();
       selection.addRange(range);
   }
};

$(document).on("click", "#addNewBullet", function() {
  $('<li class="bullet editable" contentEditable="true">Your new bullet</li>').insertBefore('#addNewBullet').focus().selectText();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bulletPoints" id="bullets">
  <li class="bullet" contenteditable="true">Bullet1</li>
  <li class="bullet" contenteditable="true">Bullet2</li>
  <li class="bullet" contenteditable="true">Bullet3</li>
  <div id="addNewBullet">+ Add</div>
</ul>
```